# how can I print all the extensions values on Axum Extensions Struct?

Tags: rust, rust-axum

If I run this

```
        println!(
        "->> {:<12} - Ctx: extensions {:?}",
        "MIDDLEWARE",
        parts.extensions.clone()
        );
```

the output is

```
->> MIDDLEWARE   - Ctx: extensions Extensions
```

I know it has 6 extensions when I run

```
parts.extensions.len()
```

I created only one with one struct called CTX

I know how to return my one, but I want a way of debug printing all the values inside the extension, The extension uses a map with types as keys, and I want to see all the keys and values inside.

I didn't find anything inside the doc of the struct Extension, I am a beginner in Rust, maybe it has a way direct by code.
https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/struct.Extension.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.

[`Extensions`](https://docs.rs/http/1.0.0/http/struct.Extensions.html) stores its data in (essentially) a `HashMap<TypeId, Box<dyn Any>>`. There is no requirement that the values stored within implement `Debug`, `Display`, or any other representable trait. And you can't get the concrete type from a `Box<dyn Any>` unless you already know (statically) what type it could be. Equally, you can't get any generic information from the `TypeId` even if the `Extensions` exposed it.

So unfortunately, your only insight would be from querying what types are relevant to you and print those using a series of `if let Some(ext) = parts.extensions.get::<MyExt>() { ... }` or similar.